# Testing connection to server on Android

Tags: android, sql-server, testing, server, connection

I want to test the connection to my localhost ( or any URL ) , i made a simple code to test, i add the needed permission to manifest , but the fonction still returning "false".

here's my code :

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String adrs = "http://wwww.google.com";
    int time = 10000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        isConnectedToServer(adrs,time);



        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

          if (isConnectedToServer(adrs,time) == true) { Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Connecté !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
                else {Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Connexion perdue",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}



                isConnectedToServer(adrs,time);


            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isConnectedToServer(String url, int timeout) {
        try{
            URL myUrl = new URL(url);
            URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
            connection.connect();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Connecté !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle your exceptions
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Connexion perdue",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fisher.testconnection">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you connecting to the internet through a proxy ?

Comment: Can you put e.printStackTrace(); in catch block? And paste the message you get over here??

Comment: are you developing on Marshamallow? Then you need to request runtime permissions

Comment: if it doesn´t work, the easiest way to find out why is to Log. the error. An exception must been thrown here, so whats the stacktrace?

Comment: @SouravKanta no not with proxy

Comment: Everything depends on the thrown exception before you return false... (and you can also format your code correctly...)

Comment: @Opiatefuchs yes on Marshmallow , what should i add ?

Comment: DO not use URLConnection because it's old and crappy. Use OkHttp insted. It goes with Retrofit library, which is kinda awesome and I think you would need it.

Comment: @alexeypolusov thanks , i will it try and come back

Comment: refer to http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html . No matter what exactly the issue is here, every permission has to be requested at runtime since marshmallow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop this class in your project ,**change url** and execute the task to fetch network speed and connectivity status of your server.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class NetworkSpeedCheckTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private static final int TIMEOUT = 30000;

    /**
     * @param networkSped
     */
    public NetworkSpeedCheckTask(TextView networkSped, Context context) {
        this.networkSped = networkSped;
        this.context = context;
    }

    String linkSpeed3G = "0 Kb/s";

    TextView networkSped;

    private Context context;

    /**
     * Before starting background do some work.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        if (null != networkSped)
            networkSped.setText("fetching");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {

            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            HttpGet httpRequest;
            httpRequest = new HttpGet(new URL("Http://Google.com").toURI());

            final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT);

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpClient.execute(httpRequest);

            long endTime = System.nanoTime();

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);

            // You can re-check the size of your file
            final long contentLength = bufHttpEntity.getContentLength();

            linkSpeed3G = internetSpeed((endTime - startTime), contentLength, false);

            // Bandwidth : size(KB)/time(s)
            float bandwidth = contentLength / ((endTime - startTime) * 1000);

            Log.d("NetworkManger", "-----------[BENCHMARK] Dowload time :" + (endTime - startTime) + " ms");

            // Log
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            linkSpeed3G = "Failure";
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            linkSpeed3G = "Failure";
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            linkSpeed3G = "Failure";
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            linkSpeed3G = "Failure";
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }

        return linkSpeed3G;

    }

    /**
     * Update list ui after process finished.
     */
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        if (null != networkSped) {

            networkSped.setText(linkSpeed3G);
            if (linkSpeed3G.equalsIgnoreCase("Failure")) {
                networkSped.setTextColor(0xE43F3F);
            } else {
                networkSped.setTextColor(0xff669900);
            }

        }

        Toast.makeText(context, "linkSpeed3G " + linkSpeed3G, 3000).show();
    }

    public static String internetSpeed(long nSecs, long bytes, boolean showBits) {

        if (nSecs != 0) {

            BigDecimal secondsBigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(nSecs).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000000000), 2,
                    RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            // long secs = nSecs / 1000000000;

            if (showBits) {
                BigDecimal bitsBigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(bytes * 8);
                // long bits = bytes * 8;

                if (secondsBigDecimal.signum() == 1) {

                    // float speed = bits / secs;
                    BigDecimal speeedBigDecimal = bitsBigDecimal.divide(secondsBigDecimal, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

                    long Kbit = 1024;
                    long Mbit = Kbit * 1024;
                    long Gbit = Mbit * 1024;

                    float speed = speeedBigDecimal.floatValue();

                    if (speed < Kbit)
                        return String.valueOf(speed) + " bit/Sc";
                    if (speed > Kbit && speed < Mbit)
                        return String.valueOf(speed / Kbit) + " Kb/S";
                    if (speed > Mbit && speed < Gbit)
                        return String.valueOf(speed / Mbit) + " Mb/S";
                    if (speed > Gbit)
                        return String.valueOf(speed / Gbit) + " Gb/S";
                }
                return "???";

            } else {

                BigDecimal bitsBigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(bytes);
                // long bits = bytes * 8;

                if (secondsBigDecimal.signum() == 1) {

                    // float speed = bits / secs;
                    BigDecimal speeedBigDecimal = bitsBigDecimal.divide(secondsBigDecimal, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

                    long Kbit = 1024;
                    long Mbit = Kbit * 1024;
                    long Gbit = Mbit * 1024;

                    float speed = speeedBigDecimal.floatValue();

                    if (speed < Kbit)
                        return String.valueOf(speed) + " Byte/Sc";
                    if (speed > Kbit && speed < Mbit)
                        return String.valueOf(speed / Kbit) + " KB/S";
                    if (speed > Mbit && speed < Gbit)
                        return String.valueOf(speed / Mbit) + " MB/S";
                    if (speed > Gbit)
                        return String.valueOf(speed / Gbit) + " GB/S";
                }
                return "???";

            }
        }
        return "###";
    }

}
```

All you need to write one line to check server connectivity and network speed

```
new NetworkSpeedCheckTask(null, getApplicationContext()).execute();
```

Comment: how can i set the timeout ??